# how to get default value in enum if not exists value

Tags: c#

I have this enum:

```
public enum EnumMoney
{
    SDI= 1,
    RCV= 2,
    STIS= 3
}
```

if I retrieve the value with a non-existent code it returns the entire code.

Sample:

```
var selectedEnum =  (EnumMoney) 1;
var selectedEnumNoExist =  (EnumMoney) 200;
```

`selectedEnumNoExist` will return "200". I actually want it to return an empty string.

Comment: `enum` is an int, not a string. How are you formatting it?

Comment: @Charlieface `((EnumMoney)200).ToString()` returns "200"

Comment: Since enums are by default an int, setting a variable to a string when trying to cast an int into the enum when the enum value doesn't exist doesn't even make sense, and is not possible.  You can't have a variable be conditionally different types--it's either all one type or all another type.  You will have to use an if statement to check if the value exists in the enum: if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EnumMoney), 200)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Enum.IsDefined static method to check if enum exists and then do something with it.

For example:

```
var someValue = 200;
var stringValue = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EnumMoney), someValue) ? someValue.ToString() : "";
```

You can find more about Enum.IsDefined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-5.0

Comment: I would prefer using the generic version `IsDefined<TEnum>(TEnum)`: `Enum.IsDefined(selectedEnumNoExist)`